# columns that gives Cumulative sum for different types of variables with the help of r

Tags: r, sorting, subset, cumulative-sum

i have a data that looks like this

```
    structure(c("Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", "Material Efficiencie", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Material Efficiencie", 
"Material Efficiencie", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Material Efficiencie", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Material Efficiencie", "Manufacturing Excell", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Material Efficiencie", "NPI Efficiencies", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Material Efficiencie", "Material Efficiencie", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Material Efficiencie", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", "Material Efficiencie", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Material Efficiencie", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Material Efficiencie", "Material Efficiencie", "Material Efficiencie", 
"Material Efficiencie", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "NPI Efficiencies", "Manufacturing Excell", 
"Manufacturing Excell", "Material Efficiencie", "NPI Efficiencies", 
"NPI Efficiencies", "28859", "15134", "29429", "14214", "37988", 
"15328", "42679", "46206", "43311", "8158", "29937", "6021", 
"5581", "44627", "36779", "15888", "20088", "42170", "11560", 
"16401", "30293", "27682", "44574", "20240", "10176", "45920", 
"40615", "28510", "23527", "35717", "12608", "30585", "1344", 
"30179", "38589", "18135", "32662", "577", "47836", "36944", 
"8946", "36730", "6499", "47177", "31564", "17612", "19799", 
"43469", "780", "29003", "729", "39209", "8237", "12442", "40877", 
"45338", "44977", "2081", "47886", "19948", "38960", "27127", 
"33186", "36972", "29774", "24197", "47513", "21171", "10992", 
"2630", "39740", "38639", "8373", "7932", "44641", "8877", "4256", 
"47425", "4972", "11793", "48437", "15102", "30181", "23058", 
"27086", "11750", "32797", "33320", "42980", "2712", "3360", 
"18773", "34625", "48207", "18044", "16727", "36327", "38051", 
"39081", "35858", "11747", "32221", "45342", "25444", "27538", 
"3725", "29636", "37667", "24387", "43088", "49972", "39308", 
"17497", "26198", "42199", "20640", "26455", "42792", "36511", 
"16867", "34142", "10629", "15415", "38989", "24381", "45988", 
"19603", "40886", "16616", "13004", "8370", "34725", "17915", 
"29838", "38500", "10620", "45602", "11911", "38119", "308", 
"37473", "17560", "14887", "30872", "7622", "20169", "38494", 
"12728", "14816", "37183", "18602", "157", "49615", "12902", 
"31344", "15606", "30386", "49746", "26466", "19784", "9326", 
"33639", "25323", "31404", "20045", "45788", "49454", "13271", 
"44675", "44926", "33041"), .Dim = c(171L, 2L))
```

Now what i want to do is create 3 different columns which gives me the cumulative savings for material efficiencie, NPI efficiencies and Manufacturing excell. is there any way to do that. By column i mean 3 different columns for different savings types.

Answer (score 0):

One option is `

```
library(stringi)
stri_list2matrix(split(m1[,2], m1[,1]))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
lst <- lapply(split(m1[,2], m1[,1]), as.numeric)
d1 <- data.frame(lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
d1
#   Manufacturing.Excell Material.Efficiencie NPI.Efficiencies
#1                24387                 8877            44574
#2                   NA                   NA            19603
#3                   NA                   NA            29838
#4                   NA                   NA            20169
```

If we need cumulative sum

```
d1[] <- lapply(d1, function(x) cumsum(replace(x, is.na(x), 0)))
d1
#  Manufacturing.Excell Material.Efficiencie NPI.Efficiencies
#1                24387                 8877            44574
#2                24387                 8877            64177
#3                24387                 8877            94015
#4                24387                 8877           114184
```